# Are there infinitely many primes numbers for congruece class 0,1,2 mod 3

Tags: number-theory

I know how to prove 1 (mod 3) has infinately many prime by using 3 modulo 4 has infinately many prime.

But I dont know how to prove 0 (mod 3) and 2( mod 3).

Comment: Wouldn't the 0 congruence class have only one prime?

Comment: oh .. because 0 ( mod 3) means every number which congruent to  (mod 3) should be 3 , 6, 9, 12, 15 ....   So only 3 can be congruent and prime number. Is it right ?

Comment: your proof that there are infinitely primes congruent to $1\bmod 3$ looks kind of sketchy by the way.

Answer (score 4):

The proof for an infinite number of primes that are of the form $2 \bmod 3$ is relatively simple compared to the proof for primes of the form $1\bmod 3$.

Consider a finite list of primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots p_s$ all of the form $p_i \equiv 2\bmod 3$. Then the number $N=3p_1p_2\cdots p_s - 1$ is not divisible by any of these primes, and $N$ is also of the form  $N\equiv 2\bmod 3$. So the prime factorization of $N$ must contain at least one other prime of the form $q\equiv 2\bmod 3$, since multiplying together primes of other residue classes will not produce this.

Since any finite list of primes of the form $2\bmod 3$ allows us to find an additional such prime, there must be an infinite number of primes $2\bmod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there cannot be infinitely primes that are $0\bmod 3$, the only such prime is $3$.

To prove that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $2\bmod 3$ Suppose that $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$ are the only such primes. The number  $(p_1p_2\dots p_n)^2+2$ must have a prime factor congruent to $2\bmod 3$, but it cannot be among the set $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$, this is a contradiction. So the number of such primes cannot be finite.

Comment: Two comments: "$p_1,\dots, p_n$ are the only such *odd* primes," and I think you want to look at either $(p_1\cdots p_n)^2 + 1$ or $3 p_1\cdots p_n + 2$ ($(p_1\cdots p_n)^2 + 2\equiv 1 + 2\equiv 0\pmod{3}$).